Hypothesis test
I need to test the difference between two coefficients (I have two different regressions), how I did:
car<- mtcars


first<- lm(formula =  vs ~ gear + carb,
                 data = car)

second<- lm(formula =  vs ~ gear + disp,
           data = car)


coef_diff <- coef(first)["gear"] - coef(second)["gear"]
t.test(coef(first)["gear"], coef(second)["gear"],choice= "two.side",var.equal= TRUE)

The message I receveid:
Error in t.test.default(coef(first)["gear"], coef(second)["gear"], choice = "two.side",  : 
number insufficient of observations 


You can’t do a t test with just two numbers. If you need statistical advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. This is not really a specific programming question that’s appropriate for Stack Overflow.

You could use the linearHypothesis function from the car package, which can test whether two coefficients in the same model are equal.
third <- lm(formula =  vs ~ gear + carb + disp, data = car)

car::linearHypothesis(third, "carb = disp")


Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
carb - disp = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: vs ~ gear + carb + disp

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
1     29 3.4685                              
2     28 3.1136  1   0.35489 3.1914 0.08486 .

